# Front-end Dev Env set up issue

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Have trouble in starting my development frontend server.

I tried setting up my DEV environment and my node version is 12.12.0 and my npm version is 6.14.4. When i try to start my app, it says starting the server and then it carshes down with this error message.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (598:33)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |     }

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Doesn't seem to work, I also tried doing this (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-694191642) it failed as well.

Any help to fix this is appreciated.

Comment: make sure that you have the ```@babel/preset-env``` preset installed and configured correctly.

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida I have installed @babel/preset-env and how do i ensure the configs are correct?